# NSDateFormatter parsing timezone

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to parse a date string that doesn't include a timezone. The date string will always be in GMT. When I construct a new `NSDateFormatter` the result is 3 hours ahead of GMT, and when I set the `timeZone` on the date formatter to GMT it comes out 3 hours behind. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a quick playground demonstrating the problem:

```
import Foundation
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss a"
let date1 = formatter.dateFromString("2/8/2016 3:43:32 PM")!
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")!
let date2 = formatter.dateFromString("2/8/2016 3:43:32 PM")!
print("Expect: 2016-02-08 15:43:32 +0000")
print("Got:    \(date1)")
print("        \(date2)")
```

The output:

```
Expect: 2016-02-08 15:43:32 +0000
Got:    2016-02-08 18:43:32 +0000
        2016-02-08 12:43:32 +0000
```

Comment: Here's a fun factoid: If you change to `formatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss"` and input `"2/8/2016 15:43:32"` you get the correct time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `"M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss a"` -> `"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a"`. The hour should not be capitalized (capitalized H means 24 hour time). Verified in playground.